# Problem with JBoss > 5 in Ubuntu Server Service Script

Tags: shell, syntax, jboss5.x, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-server

Well.

Hi everybody again.

I have a trouble with some script that I wanna to be executed as a Service in an Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS PC. This is the script:

```
#! /bin/sh

JBOSS_BIN=/usr/local/jboss/bin
JBOSS_START_SCRIPT=$JBOSS_BIN/run.sh 
JBOSS_STOP_SCRIPT=/usr/local/jboss/bin/shutdown.sh
JBOSS_BIND_ADDR=${JBOSS_HOST:-"-b 0.0.0.0"}

ECHO=/bin/echo
TEST=/usr/bin/test

$TEST -x $JBOSS_START_SCRIPT || exit 0
$TEST -x $JBOSS_STOP_SCRIPT || exit 0

start(){
    $ECHO "Starting JBoss"
    su - jboss -c $JBOSS_START_SCRIPT $JBOSS_BIND_ADDR "> /dev/null &"
    $ECHO "."
}

stop(){
    $ECHO "Stopping JBoss"
    su - jboss -c $JBOSS_STOP_SCRIPT -S
    $ECHO "."
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    restart)
        stop
        sleep 30
        start
        ;;
    *)
        $ECHO "Usage: jboss (start|stop|restart)"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Well That script is not working because I don't know exactly how to put "> /dev/null &" for being executed correctly. See, if I do the command in a hand in the gnome-terminal it works, but when I write it in the script and execute it, it fails. So I don't know what is working wrong. Perhaps some buggy syntax? plz help me; I'm really stuck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave off the quotes that you have around `> /dev/null &`

```
su - jboss -c $JBOSS_START_SCRIPT $JBOSS_BIND_ADDR > /dev/null &
```

Comment: are u sure. I did as you wrote here but It still doesn't work. what am i doing wrong? Thanks in advice.

Comment: nop, That's the big deal, I don't see any error messages. See, I think that is Ubuntu Server the troublemaker here (maybe is not respecting debian way).

Comment: @ingcarlos: Where is `jboss` located? Have you tried specifying the full path to it? Perhaps: `su - $JBOSS_BIN/jboss -c $JBOSS_START_SCRIPT $JBOSS_BIND_ADDR > /dev/null &` if that's appropriate.

Comment: Tnx. @Dennis Willamson. Your ans was rite. My problem was because I was asleep, and When a take some rest and Wake up, I found that I need a do "sudo update-rc.d jboss defaults" that's it. Tnx 4 u support.